# Issue with PHP mail() function not working despite trying multiple solutions

Tags: php, html, email, smtp

I am facing an issue with the PHP mail() function where it's not working at all. I have tried multiple MTA (Mail Transfer Agent) solutions like sendmail, postfix, and exim, but none of them seem to work for me. I have also searched extensively online for a solution, but nothing seems to work.

Here is the HTML code for the form I am using:

```
<!--  contact form area start -->
            <div
              class="col-lg-8 col-md-6 col-sm-12 m-25px-b"
              data-aos="fade-right"
              data-aos-duration="1000"
              data-aos-delay="200"
            >
              <div class="contact-form-box">
                <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="php/sendmail.php">
                  <div class="message col">
                    <p class="email-loading alert alert-warning">
                      <img
                        src="assets/images/loading.gif"
                        alt=""
                      />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sending...
                    </p>
                    <p class="email-success alert alert-success">
                      <i class="icofont-check-circled"></i> Your quote has
                      successfully been sent.
                    </p>
                    <p class="email-failed alert alert-danger">
                      <i class="icofont-close-circled"></i> Something went
                      wrong!
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="mb13">
                    <input
                      name="name"
                      class="contact-name"
                      id="contact-name"
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="Your Name"
                      required=""
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div class="mb13">
                    <input
                      name="email"
                      class="contact-email"
                      id="contact-email"
                      type="email"
                      placeholder="Your Email"
                      required=""
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div class="mb13">
                    <input
                      name="subject"
                      class="contact-subject"
                      id="contact-subject"
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="Subject"
                      required=""
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div class="mb30">
                    <textarea
                      name="message"
                      class="contact-message"
                      id="contact-message"
                      placeholder="Your Message"
                      required=""
                    ></textarea>
                  </div>
                  <button class="button button__primary align-items-center">
                    <span>Send Now</span>
                  </button>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--  contact form area end -->
```

And here is the sendmail.php code I have used for the form:

```
<?php
// Variables
$name = trim($_POST['name']);
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$subject = trim($_POST['subject']);
$message = trim($_POST['message']);


if( isset($name) && isset($email) ) {

    // Avoid Email Injection and Mail Form Script Hijacking
    $pattern = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:|to:)/i";
    if( preg_match($pattern, $name) || preg_match($pattern, $email) || preg_match($pattern, $message) ) {
        exit;
    }

    // Email will be send
    $to = "testmail@gmail.com"; //  email address
    $sub = "$subject from test"; //  email subject
    // HTML Elements for Email Body
    $body = <<<EOD
    <strong>Name:</strong> $name <br>
    <strong>Email:</strong> <a href="mailto:$email?subject=feedback" "email me">$email</a> <br> <br>
    <strong>Message:</strong> $message <br>
EOD;
//Must end on first column
    
    $headers = "From: $name <$email>\r\n";
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    // PHP email sender
    mail($to, $sub, $body, $headers);
}


?>
```

I would greatly appreciate any help or guidance in resolving this issue. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Check it's running under root permission or it cannot connect.

Comment: Yeah, it's running under the root! I also checked the logs, and I didn't find any issues there.

Comment: What about php.ini settings...

Comment: I don't touch it. The mail() isn't working by default? Do I need to modify the php.ini file?

Comment: "Yes", see [mail function] in the php.ini.     https://netcorecloud.com/tutorials/sendmail-in-php-complete-guide/

Comment: Save yourself the headache and use PHPMailer with a 3rd-party mail provider.